# Comparing PostgreSQL JSON arrays for any matches

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to compare two JSON arrays in PostgreSQL to see if there are any matches. For instance I would expect true when comparing `'["foo", "bar", "baz"]'` and `'["qux", "bar"]'` and false when comparing `'["foo", "bar", "baz"]'` and `'["qux", "quz"]'`. Is it possible to do that in PostgreSQL without creating a function?

Comment: You can do it with native arrays, but not with JSON as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `?|` operator and casting to text then translating to create an array

```
SELECT interests ?| TRANSLATE(tags::TEXT, '[]','{}')::TEXT[]
```

`interests` and `tags` being jsonb containing arrays

```
SELECT '["foo", "bar", "baz"]'::JSONB ?| TRANSLATE('["qux", "bar"]'::JSONB::TEXT, '[]','{}')::TEXT[]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 select ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements('["foo", "bar", "baz"]')::text)
 && ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements('["qux", "bar"]')::text)
```

Comment: If you use `jsonb_array_elements` and remove the `::text` cast, then this will work with any JSON type too (even for embedded arrays and objects).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert json arrays to regular ones and use [the array operator &&](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). You need the simple function:

```
create or replace function to_text_array(jsonb)
returns text[] language sql immutable as $$
    select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text($1))
$$;
```

Example:

```
with my_table(arr1, arr2) as (
values
    ('["foo", "bar", "baz"]'::jsonb, '["qux", "bar"]'::jsonb),
    ('["foo", "bar", "baz"]', '["qux", "quz"]')
)

select *, to_text_array(arr1) && to_text_array(arr2) as match
from my_table

         arr1          |      arr2      | match 
-----------------------+----------------+-------
 ["foo", "bar", "baz"] | ["qux", "bar"] | t
 ["foo", "bar", "baz"] | ["qux", "quz"] | f
(2 rows)
```